# Apple TV and Podcasts

Tags: appletv, podcasts

I have an Apple TV 2, the one with a max of 720p. If I decide to upgrade to an Apple TV 3 for its 1080p goodness (or an Apple TV 4 in the future if/when it's released), when I log in with my Apple ID, will my list of favorite Podcasts transfer over? Or will I need to add them all over again?

Answer (score 1):

I think it does. Because of iCloud, the stuff in your Apple account will transfer to other devices. For example, if I enable app-sharing with iCloud on my iPhone and I download Temple Run, Temple RUn will also be downloaded into my iPad too. so I think that this will work with the Apple TV 3.